# maven include different files for different profile

Tags: maven

I want to have different spring configuration files for different maven profiles. [Filtering](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html) is close to what i want, but it change only properties inside one file. What i want is include/exclude and rename files depending on profile. For example i have files profile1-config.xml and profile2-config.xml. For profile1 build profile1-config.xml is renamed to config.xml and profile2-config.xml is excluded from build. For profile2 build profile2-config.xml is renamed to config.xml and profile1-config.xml is excluded from build.
 Is this possible in maven?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea won't work that way but if you modify it, it will do as follows:

Say you rather create conf folders for every profile and suck it those files.

```
src/main/conf
  |-/profile1/conf.xml
  |-/profile2/conf.xml
```

and so forth. Configure your profile take in those files. If you intend to deploy a different config for some server, it's best working with additional modules and war overlays because you cannot deploy multiple configs of the same module project at once in Nexus or a local repo. More over, consider that many profile will clutter your pom and introduce more complexity to the build.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to use the [copy-resources](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) goal in maven-resources-plugin.

You can create a folder to hold all your profiles, for example:

```
profiles
    |-profile1
    |-profile2
```

And in your pom.xml, you can have those settings:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}/profiles/profile1</directory>
                                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>profile2</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}/profiles/profile2</directory>
                                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```